# Regex empty string or two-five commas

Tags: regex, expression

I need a regex expression which captures the following strings:

```
An actually empty value; which i know is (^$)
,aowett1951,
,01521045ww,32052w352,
,23052kwtw,3032w502,5252a352,
,1410ww5,352w351,w532152,52352352,
```

The values in between the commas can be any length and can contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what regexp-flavor? What have you tried?. Will a simple `([a-zA-z0-9]+)` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a pattern like this:

```
^(,([a-zA-Z0-9]+,){1,4})?$
```

1. `^` matches the beginning of the string (or line in multiline mode)
2. `(...)?` creates an optional group.

   1. `,` matches a literal comma
   2. `(...){1,4}` creates a group that may repeat one to four times.

      1. `[a-zA-Z0-9]+,` matches any sequence of one or more Latin letters or decimal digits, followed by a comma.
3. `$` matches the end of the string (or line in multiline mode)

[**Demonstration**](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%2C%28%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B%2C%29%7B1%2C4%7D%29%3F%24&input=Should%20match%3A%0A%0A%2Caowett1951%2C%0A%2C01521045ww%2C32052w352%2C%0A%2C23052kwtw%2C3032w502%2C5252a352%2C%0A%2C1410ww5%2C352w351%2Cw532152%2C52352352%2C%0A%0AShould%20not%20match%0A%2C%0A%2C1410ww5%2C352w351%2Cw532152%2C52352352%2C52352352%2C)